# How do I convert a positive number to negative in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, numbers

How do I convert a positive Integer to a negative with Delphi? I know you could use `ABS(int)` to convert a negative to a positive, but I need it to convert positive to negative.

Comment: If you know that `a` is positive, and you want to obtain the negative number with the same distance to the origin, then you simply do `-a`. If you don't know the sign of `a`, and you want to make sure that it is negative or zero in the sense that you replace `a` with `-a` only if `a` is positive, then you can do like RBA suggested, but the approach by Mef is much neater: `-abs(a)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

from what I know there is no function for that. you can make

```
if yourvariable > 0 then
    yourvariable := -yourvariable;
```

Comment: Thanks yah thats right, dumb of me same as c++ lol, i was thinking delphi more as visual basic.

Comment: @Tprice, Visual Basic has had the **unary minus operator** just like Delphi for many years.

Comment: O, ive never used it on their i havent used it since Visual Basic 6 i refuse to use .Net .

Comment: **All** languages have unary minus operator

Comment: you need to do type checking. Consider: i: Byte; i:=10. -abs(i) will give 246 as result.

Comment: @PieterB: No, it will now. But of course, `byte(-10)` yields 246, but that is obvious, since a byte is unsigned.

Comment: did he just use the walrus operator? what a bad ass! Shame it isnt supported on my current version of Python :(

Answer (score 45):

If you want to be absolutely sure to get a negative result (or zero), use

```
number := -abs(number)
```

Comment: shouldn't that be: number:= -1 * abs(number); ?

Comment: @TomHagen: -x = -1 * x ∀x ∈ ℝ.

Answer (score 5):

Ehhh... Too late but `number := number * -1;` would work too, but this change the symbol of any number, negative to positive and backwards... To ensure a negative value go with @Mef Answer

---

**EDIT:** even later, but `number := 0 - number;` would work too... This just reverses the symbol as well

Comment: What does the ":=" do?

Answer (score 2):

Let `n` be your number and the formula for `n-(n*2) = -n`