# Convert positive integer to negative integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
  def negate_amount
    amount = model.amount.to_s
    ("-" + amount).to_i
  end
```

is there a better way to turn positive integer to negative?

The code above works, but is there a ruby or rails function for that? Without doing math operations?

Comment: Math operations *are* methods. Unary negation is just a fancy way of calling the [`-@`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-2D-40) method so `-int` is just a short form of `int.-@` or `int.send(:-@)`.

Answer (score 17):

You can just use the unary `-` operator:

```
def negate_amount
    -model.amount
end
```

Answer (score 12):

Similar question to [How do I convert a positive number to negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968707/how-do-i-convert-a-positive-number-to-negative).
But in summary, if you are always expecting a negative answer you could simply say

```
def negate_amount
    amount = -(model.abs)
end
```

Otherwise, if you simply want the function to return a negative of the integer : assuming negating a negative number returns a positive number, then you would use

```
def negate_amount
    amount = -(model)
end
```

Comment: `abs` function is not found?

Comment: Sorry, need to brush up on my ruby, try `-(model.abs)`. And the abs isn't necessary, it just ensures that the return is going to be a negative number. Depending on functionality, this may or may not be what you want. Do you want a negative number to come back negative or positive?
If that works I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just multiply per -1 the amount.

Comment: Ah so there's no function for that. I see. I'll just do Math operations then. Thanks for confirming :D

Comment: @XirukiTepe the method is [`Fiuxnum#*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A]), `num * -1` is syntactic sugar for `num.send(:*, -1)`

Answer (score 2):

How about if you multiply it by negative one?

```
  def negate_amount
    amount = model.amount.to_s
    amount = amount*-1
  end
```

Comment: You can't multiply a string by `-1`

Comment: i didn't notice that. 
then use .to_i instead

Comment: amount=amount.to_i *-1

Comment: According to the question, `amount` is already an integer :-)

Comment: Hmm, right. I also didn't notice that.
So she's trying to simply ask a yes or no question.  which I don't know if there exist such method and I won't do such thing negating a number using string.